# Unable to load image and data in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Problem is that I have NEWS-FEED module, in which I have taken data from server in which all title of news will be displayed on left div and after clicking on that news title , description regarding the news will be displayed on right div, in the code below, it simply shows data but don't know how to add image of that news.

**CODE:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-show = "dataFromRest" ng-repeat = "x in dataFromRest.posts" >
<div class="tittle">        
    <div style=" width:25%;">   
       <b ng-click="$index" style="text-decoration: none;">
         <a href="#" ng-click="textshow(showDiv = ! showDiv)" style="text-decoration: none;"># {{x.title}} 
         </a>
         <hr>
         </a>
        </b>
    </div>  
</div>  
<div class="text">              
    <div style="width: 70% ;float:right; background-color: white;">
        <div ng-show="showDiv">{{x.text}} </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Depends how the data is formed in `dataFromRest.posts` variable. You'll have to give us some dummy value to proceed

Comment: adding to vivek comment, if its coming from response you can use img tag with ng-src directive

Comment: yes data coming from response and i got output , but instead of                  [  <a href="#" ng-click="textshow(showDiv = ! showDiv)" style="text-decoration: none;"># {{x.title}}      ] of this textshow i want this through function in javascript